# Groovy make methods visible from one script to another

Tags: java, groovy

I have a script with utility methods I would like to access from my other script.

I load my script like this in my java code

```
static {
    GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
    //This is the script that has the utility 
    groovyUtils = shell.parse(new InputStreamReader(MyJavaClass.class.getResourceAsStream("scripts/json/MyUtils.groovy")));
    //This is the script that does thing
    groovyScript = shell.parse(new InputStreamReader(MyJavaClass.class.getResourceAsStream("scripts/json/MyScript.groovy")));
}
```

I would like to expose the methods from `MyUtils.groovy` to be usable in `MyScript.groovy` (and also other scripts in the future)

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of ways how you can achieve this.

You're talking about *methods*, so I guess you have a class in `MyUtils.groovy`.
In this case you can specify a `Binding`, e.g.

```
def myUtils = new MyUtils()
def binding= new Binding([  method1: myUtils.&method1  ]) 
def shell= new GroovyShell(binding)

shell.evaluate(new File("scripts/json/MyScript.groovy"))
```

In the above you can reference `method1` in your script and you will end up invoking it on `myUtils` instance.

Another solution is to specify a script base-class, e.g.

```
def configuration = new CompilerConfiguration()
configuration.setScriptBaseClass('MyUtils.groovy')
def shell = new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new Binding(), configuration)
```

`MyUtils` class must extend `Script` then; all its methods are available in scripts you parse using `shell`.

---

There are essentially multiple ways how to embed / run Groovy. These are quite often discussed while designing DSLs. You can take a look e.g. [here](http://www.slideshare.net/glaforge/practical-groovy-dsl), if you haven't searched for it before.

Comment: This is also what I gathered from searching on Google/Stackoverflow but it doesn't really apply to me because 1. My scripts are in the classpath and 2. I am creating my GroovyShell in Java, not groovy.
One temporary solution I have right now is to load the text from my scripts then do `Script myScript = shell.parse(textFromUtils + System.lineSeparator() + textFromMyScript);`

Comment: @NicolasMartel *My scripts are in the classpath* - this should have no effect, just use a different input method. *I am creating my GroovyShell in Java* - this, again, should make no difference; just remove all the syntax sugar that I used.

Comment: How would you do `new Binding([  method1: myUtils.&method1  ])` in Java? I'm still a bit new to Groovy so I'm not entirely sure what that would translate into

Comment: @NicolasMartel `[ key: value]` is just a map literal, read more [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps). So in Java just pass a `HashMap` (which is what `[k:v]` is implemented as by default). `myUtils.&method1` is a method reference, so either build an anonymous `Closure` or ... pass a method reference in Java 8. There are other ways though (I gave you only 2), so choose whatever you find best.